# proc report to display dynamically

Tags: sas, sas-macro

proc report to dynamically display report using macros

1.selection criteria dynamically ex:city=Atlanta, Washington
2.dynamically pick the variables(columns) to display
3.dynamically display total

Comment: Please include anything you've tried, sample data so that we understand your current data structure and an example of the desired output.  Yes, it's possibly to write a macro to generate dynamic reports. But your question is unclear and you haven't shown an attempt at solving this yourself so at this point it does not meet SO guidelines.

Comment: Title: students report 
city atlanda,washington 
  
my dataset contains name,age,student_id,city variables

Comment: Title: students report 
city atlanda,washington 
  
my dataset contains name,age,student_id,city variables.Dynamically pick the variables(columns) to display and subset my records based on the user input for the city column

Comment: Please edit your question, don't add the items in to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In a SAS Foundation session (plain old display manager SAS, not using other SAS clients such as SAS Studio or Enterprise Guide) you can use the `WINDOWS` option

```
proc report data=sashelp.cars windows;
run;
```

In a wider environment (web client or EG) you will be creating a parameterized stored process.  There are numerous resources on the web, for instance, a Bing search for "creating a stored process report in eg" might direct you to the hands on workshop paper [Creating and Using SAS® Stored Processes with SAS® Enterprise Guide®](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/135-30.pdf)